# Keras Custom Standardization

Tags: keras, nlp, preprocessor

I am trying to add a custom function to a tensor of dtype string. The function removes html tags and replaces email addresses with the string *email*. This codes works perfectly fine.

**This part is working**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import preprocessing as pp
from textacy import preprocessing as prep
from tensorflow.keras.layers import TextVectorization
import string
import re

def repl_email(text):
    text=prep.replace.emails(text.numpy().decode('UTF-8'), '_EMAIL_')
    return text

def custom_standardization(input_data):
    input_data=tf.map_fn(fn=repl_email,elems=input_data,fn_output_signature=None)
    lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_data)
    stripped_html = tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, "<br />", "")
    return tf.strings.regex_replace(
        stripped_html, f"[{re.escape(string.punctuation)}]", ""
    )

txt_lyr=tf.constant(['This is my email address some_email@yahoo.com<br /><br />',
 'This is another email address another_email@yahoo.com<br /><br />'])
j=custom_standardization(txt_lyr)
print(j)

>>>tf.Tensor([b'this is my email address email' b'this is another email address email'], shape=(2,), dtype=string)
```

Moving on, I try to do this on the IMDB Move dataset as used in an example [here](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_classification_from_scratch/), it produces text_ds ( a tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.MapDataset ). I am trying to run the custom function containing the tf.map_fn throws an error.

**This part is not working**

```
batch_size = 32
max_features = 20000
embedding_dim = 128
sequence_length = 500

raw_train_ds = pp.text_dataset_from_directory(
    "aclImdb/train",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=1337,
)

vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(
    standardize=custom_standardization,
    max_tokens=max_features,
    output_mode="int",
    output_sequence_length=sequence_length,
)

text_ds = raw_train_ds.map(lambda x, y: x)
vectorize_layer.adapt(text_ds)
```

I get the this error.
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'

I understand , if I were to iterate through text_ds , it generates batches of tensors of size 32, like "i" below , which happens to be a tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor

```
n=0
for i in text_ds:
    print(n,len(i),i.numpy())
    n+=1
    if n>3:
        break
```

Comment: That's because `tf.data` operations run in graph mode, hence you can not call `numpy()`.

Comment: Thanks @Frightera, however if I remove the line with map_fn, the function runs fine. Is there a way around to apply map_fn to all the strings in the tf.data